# no default gateway on interface that is set up with DHCP on CentOS7

Tags: networking, dhcp, linux-networking, centos7, networkmanager

I am using CentOS7 with multiple interfaces (ens161, ens192, ens224, ens256). The box has all static IP's with the exception of one interface that is set up to DHCP (ens192). ens192 is set up as onboot=no. I have a static route set in /etc/sysconfig/network. This works fine. The issue is if I want to bring up ens192 and use the default gateway that it is given by DHCP. I delete the static route that is set in /etc/sysocnfig/network by doing

```
ip route del 0/0
```

I then do ifup ens192 the interface will come up with an IP however when I do:

```
route
```

I will not see the default gw that the server gives out. The only way to get this to work is to start the NetworkManager process. The reason I have it disabled by default is because for some reason when NetworkManager is running if I do a

```
 service network restart
```

it does not honor the

```
onboot=no
```

that I have set up in ifcfg-ens192.

The only current solution I see to get his working is to write a script that will do:

```
ip route del 0/0
echo ''> /etc/sysconfig/network
service network restart
ip route del 0/0
ifup ens192
```

That's the only thing that seems to work which is a bit "hackey".

Comment: Why are you trying to run `service network restart`? Don't do this on a system running NetworkManager.

Comment: @MichaelHampton As I wrote above NetworkManager is disabled as it ignores onboot=yes.

Comment: I think I found an easy alternative. It is to simply set the GATEWAY in the ifcfg scripts and then bring down one interface and bring up the other.

Answer (score 1):

i just run in to this issue and after a while looking arround, i found out the source of this problem is the "DEFROUTE=no" in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg- , change this no into yes and everything will work fine. Basicly this is for a multiple network interface that you can set default gateway and save the info, but you can change which interface you chose as overall default gateway